# TypeScript: Possible to declare a specific sequence type in array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am currently writing a declaration file for an external library and one of its functions accepts an array of elements in a specific order. For example, in the code below strings `"A", "B", "C"` should always appear in the same order together followed by other elements.

```
let specificArray      = ['A', 'B', 'C',  1, 2, 3] // ✔ Correct Usage
let specificArrayTwo   = [ 1, 2, 'A', 'B', 'C', 3] // ✔ Correct Usage
let specificArrayThree = [ 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 'C', 3] // ✕ Wrong Usage
let specificArrayFour  = [ 1, 'C', 'A', 'B', 2, 3] // ✕ Wrong Usage
```

Is there any way currently to enforce this rule using TypeScript?

Comment: It is possible to create empty function which will check if argument is valid array or not. But it will work only with literal immutable arrays. Are you ok with such kind approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: "No, it cannot be done."

TypeScript only offers functionality that aids in *compile time type checking* your JavaScript code/logic. Arrays or objects do not specify a specific *order* of their elements or members. Checking the "correct" order of elements is *run time behavior* and cannot be checked specifically by TypeScript; that would go beyond the scope of TypeScript's functionality.

You could go two ways here:

- Implement some validation overhead in your library that checks any array that is passed to your library's functions. This is robust, but it could harm performance.
- Apply the GIGO principle: Garbage In, Garbage Out. Who is actually responsible for supplying correct input data to your library logic? You could consider to only document your library properly so that everybody who uses your library is informed on how it should be used correctly.

Perhaps you could also go both ways: publish some additional validation logic in your library, so that the end users of your library have the choice of validating their arrays before passing them to your library functions.

Comment: Ah okay! Yeah that absolutely makes sense. Thank you so much for a clear and concise answer!